# How can I properly change default installation directory of Windows 8 Tile Apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I've gone into regeddit and attempted to change the default location from C://program files/WindowsApps to the same directory on my E: drive.

First my apps wouldn't open, then I noticed that nothing changed. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

MS doesn't offer an official way to modify the installation directory. You can remove all installed app, change the path in the registry and try to install them again. Maybe this works.